# Add custom field to attachments in a specific category

Tags: php, categories, functions, custom-field, attachments

I have a working function that adds a meta field to all attachments (so I can enter the url of a video). I would like this field to populate only on attachments in the "video" category.

I've tried the below, by adding `in_category('video')` but that didn't work. The field still shows on all attachments.

```
function attachment_field_url( $form_fields, $post ) {

        $form_fields['video-url'] = array(
        'label' => 'Video URL',
        'input' => 'text',
        'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'video_url', true ),
        'helps' => 'Add video URL',
    );

    return $form_fields;
}

add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'attachment_field_url', 10, 2 );

function attachment_field_url_save( $post, $attachment ) {

    if( in_category('video')  && !isset ($attachment['video-url'] ) )
update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'video_url', esc_url( $attachment['video-url'] ) );                             
    return $post;
}

add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_save', 'attachment_field_url_save', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in_category` relies on a global post - it should *only* be used within the loop. Instead, use the arguments that are passed to your callback to query the categories assigned *to the post being edited* and check if one of them is `video`:

```
$cats = get_the_category( $post['ID'] );
if ( in_array( 'video', wp_list_pluck( $cats, 'slug' ) ) {
    // In "video" category
}
```

...altogether now:

```
function attachment_field_url_save( $post, $attachment ) {
    if ( isset( $attachment['video-url'] ) ) {
        $cats = get_the_category( $post['ID'] );

        if ( in_array( 'video', wp_list_pluck( $cats, 'slug' ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'video_url', esc_url( $attachment['video-url'] ) );  
        }
    }

    return $post;
}
```

Comment: Is that something I would wrap around both functions?

Also, I did find an article that says for custom attachment fields of a certain kind (for example, audio files) you wrap the function with: `if( substr($post->post_mime_type, 0, 5) == 'audio' ){
    // add your custom fields for audio files
}`

Article: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/creating-custom-fields-for-attachments-in-wordpress--net-13076

Comment: No, you would just use it instead of `in_category( 'video' )` in your save function. And yes, you can conditionally add fields depending on mime type as you have described.